# Function in R to group linear features in a scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, visualization, scatter-plot

I've got a scatterplot I've produced using `ggplot`.

The data is here:

```
Retirees<- data.frame(No_Races = c(11L, 11L, 21L, 12L, 15L, 10L, 23L, 13L, 19L, 11L, 22L, 14L, 
  17L, 33L, 12L, 45L, 15L, 55L, 22L, 41L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 26L, 23L, 
  10L, 20L, 44L, 17L, 14L, 21L, 28L, 18L, 11L, 22L, 37L, 26L, 30L, 
  15L, 23L, 31L, 47L, 12L, 20L, 16L, 36L, 37L, 29L, 21L, 17L, 68L, 
  56L, 13L, 22L, 27L, 18L, 23L, 14L, 28L, 19L, 24L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 
  35L, 25L, 36L, 31L, 26L, 21L, 37L, 16L, 32L, 27L, 11L, 22L, 33L, 
  28L, 17L, 40L, 23L, 35L, 53L, 65L, 12L, 18L, 30L, 66L, 24L, 36L, 
  48L, 49L, 25L, 63L, 19L, 38L, 32L, 45L, 13L, 26L, 78L, 39L, 52L, 
  46L, 33L, 20L, 60L, 27L, 34L, 41L, 69L, 14L, 21L, 42L, 28L, 35L, 
  57L, 50L, 36L, 29L, 22L, 81L, 37L, 15L, 38L, 23L, 46L, 31L, 48L, 
  16L, 24L, 32L, 57L, 49L, 41L, 33L, 25L, 42L, 17L, 34L, 26L, 35L, 
  18L, 27L, 54L, 45L, 37L, 28L, 47L, 19L, 57L, 29L, 39L, 10L, 20L, 
  30L, 40L, 41L, 31L, 21L, 42L, 32L, 54L, 11L, 22L, 33L, 44L, 66L, 
  67L, 45L, 34L, 23L, 69L, 46L, 35L, 47L, 59L, 71L, 36L, 12L, 24L, 
  60L, 61L, 37L, 25L, 38L, 51L, 64L, 13L, 39L, 26L, 53L, 80L, 67L, 
  27L, 68L, 55L, 14L, 42L, 28L, 43L, 58L, 29L, 44L, 74L, 15L, 45L, 
  30L, 46L, 31L, 47L, 79L, 16L, 32L, 48L, 49L, 33L, 50L, 17L, 34L, 
  52L, 35L, 53L, 18L, 72L, 36L, 54L, 37L, 56L, 19L, 38L, 39L, 20L, 
  40L, 61L, 41L, 83L, 21L, 42L, 43L, 65L, 87L, 22L, 45L, 23L, 46L, 
  93L, 47L, 71L, 24L, 72L, 49L, 25L, 100L, 51L, 26L, 52L, 27L, 
  54L, 28L, 85L, 57L, 29L, 59L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 96L, 65L, 33L, 67L, 
  34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 74L, 38L, 77L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
  45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 59L, 
  60L, 61L, 62L, 64L, 65L, 68L, 69L, 71L, 73L, 77L, 82L, 83L, 92L, 
  98L), 
  Perc_Retired = c(54.5454545454545, 45.4545454545455, 42.8571428571429, 41.6666666666667, 
      40, 40, 39.1304347826087, 38.4615384615385, 36.8421052631579, 
                         36.3636363636364, 36.3636363636364, 35.7142857142857, 35.2941176470588, 
                         33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 33.3333333333333, 
                         32.7272727272727, 31.8181818181818, 31.7073170731707, 31.5789473684211, 
                         31.25, 30.7692307692308, 30.7692307692308, 30.4347826086957, 
                         30, 30, 29.5454545454545, 29.4117647058824, 28.5714285714286, 
                         28.5714285714286, 28.5714285714286, 27.7777777777778, 27.2727272727273, 
                         27.2727272727273, 27.027027027027, 26.9230769230769, 26.6666666666667, 
                         26.6666666666667, 26.0869565217391, 25.8064516129032, 25.531914893617, 
                         25, 25, 25, 25, 24.3243243243243, 24.1379310344828, 23.8095238095238, 
                         23.5294117647059, 23.5294117647059, 23.2142857142857, 23.0769230769231, 
                         22.7272727272727, 22.2222222222222, 22.2222222222222, 21.7391304347826, 
                         21.4285714285714, 21.4285714285714, 21.0526315789474, 20.8333333333333, 
                         20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 19.4444444444444, 19.3548387096774, 19.2307692307692, 
                         19.047619047619, 18.9189189189189, 18.75, 18.75, 18.5185185185185, 
                         18.1818181818182, 18.1818181818182, 18.1818181818182, 17.8571428571429, 
                         17.6470588235294, 17.5, 17.3913043478261, 17.1428571428571, 16.9811320754717, 
                         16.9230769230769, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 
                         16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 
                         16.3265306122449, 16, 15.8730158730159, 15.7894736842105, 15.7894736842105, 
                         15.625, 15.5555555555556, 15.3846153846154, 15.3846153846154, 
                         15.3846153846154, 15.3846153846154, 15.3846153846154, 15.2173913043478, 
                         15.1515151515152, 15, 15, 14.8148148148148, 14.7058823529412, 
                         14.6341463414634, 14.4927536231884, 14.2857142857143, 14.2857142857143, 
                         14.2857142857143, 14.2857142857143, 14.2857142857143, 14.0350877192982, 
                         14, 13.8888888888889, 13.7931034482759, 13.6363636363636, 13.5802469135802, 
                         13.5135135135135, 13.3333333333333, 13.1578947368421, 13.0434782608696, 
                         13.0434782608696, 12.9032258064516, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.280701754386, 
                         12.2448979591837, 12.1951219512195, 12.1212121212121, 12, 11.9047619047619, 
                         11.7647058823529, 11.7647058823529, 11.5384615384615, 11.4285714285714, 
                         11.1111111111111, 11.1111111111111, 11.1111111111111, 11.1111111111111, 
                         10.8108108108108, 10.7142857142857, 10.6382978723404, 10.5263157894737, 
                         10.5263157894737, 10.3448275862069, 10.2564102564103, 10, 10, 
                         10, 10, 9.75609756097561, 9.67741935483871, 9.52380952380952, 
                         9.52380952380952, 9.375, 9.25925925925926, 9.09090909090909, 
                         9.09090909090909, 9.09090909090909, 9.09090909090909, 9.09090909090909, 
                         8.95522388059701, 8.88888888888889, 8.82352941176471, 8.69565217391304, 
                         8.69565217391304, 8.69565217391304, 8.57142857142857, 8.51063829787234, 
                         8.47457627118644, 8.45070422535211, 8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 
                         8.33333333333333, 8.33333333333333, 8.19672131147541, 8.10810810810811, 
                         8, 7.89473684210526, 7.84313725490196, 7.8125, 7.69230769230769, 
                         7.69230769230769, 7.69230769230769, 7.54716981132075, 7.5, 7.46268656716418, 
                         7.40740740740741, 7.35294117647059, 7.27272727272727, 7.14285714285714, 
                         7.14285714285714, 7.14285714285714, 6.97674418604651, 6.89655172413793, 
                         6.89655172413793, 6.81818181818182, 6.75675675675676, 6.66666666666667, 
                         6.66666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 6.52173913043478, 6.45161290322581, 
                         6.38297872340426, 6.32911392405063, 6.25, 6.25, 6.25, 6.12244897959184, 
                         6.06060606060606, 6, 5.88235294117647, 5.88235294117647, 5.76923076923077, 
                         5.71428571428571, 5.66037735849057, 5.55555555555556, 5.55555555555556, 
                         5.55555555555556, 5.55555555555556, 5.40540540540541, 5.35714285714286, 
                         5.26315789473684, 5.26315789473684, 5.12820512820513, 5, 5, 4.91803278688525, 
                         4.8780487804878, 4.81927710843374, 4.76190476190476, 4.76190476190476, 
                         4.65116279069767, 4.61538461538461, 4.59770114942529, 4.54545454545455, 
                         4.44444444444444, 4.34782608695652, 4.34782608695652, 4.3010752688172, 
                         4.25531914893617, 4.22535211267606, 4.16666666666667, 4.16666666666667, 
                         4.08163265306122, 4, 4, 3.92156862745098, 3.84615384615385, 3.84615384615385, 
                         3.7037037037037, 3.7037037037037, 3.57142857142857, 3.52941176470588, 
                         3.50877192982456, 3.44827586206897, 3.38983050847458, 3.33333333333333, 
                         3.2258064516129, 3.125, 3.125, 3.07692307692308, 3.03030303030303, 
                         2.98507462686567, 2.94117647058824, 2.85714285714286, 2.77777777777778, 
                         2.7027027027027, 2.7027027027027, 2.63157894736842, 2.5974025974026, 
                         2.56410256410256, 2.5, 2.4390243902439, 2.38095238095238, 2.32558139534884, 
                         2.27272727272727, 2.22222222222222, 2.17391304347826, 2.12765957446809, 
                         2.08333333333333, 2.04081632653061, 2, 1.96078431372549, 1.92307692307692, 
                         1.88679245283019, 1.85185185185185, 1.81818181818182, 1.78571428571429, 
                         1.69491525423729, 1.66666666666667, 1.63934426229508, 1.61290322580645, 
                         1.5625, 1.53846153846154, 1.47058823529412, 1.44927536231884, 
                         1.40845070422535, 1.36986301369863, 1.2987012987013, 1.21951219512195, 
                         1.20481927710843, 1.08695652173913, 1.02040816326531))
```

The data looks like this when plotted

```
ggplot(Retirees,aes(x=No_Races,y=Perc_Retired)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

There are clearly linear groups here - are there any functions in R that will allow me to group each point into one of the linear groups.

I've tried k-means clustering but unsurprisingly they don't follow the linear groups:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I get into the answer I came up with- **A Warning**:
Make sure your data doesn't have this form due to some discretization underlying the data generation process or due to having discrete values that you are then converting into percentages.

That said, even if this is an artifact, I still think its an interesting question. I ended up creating a hybrid linear-regression/k-means like thing that I think solves your problem fairly well. I am not sure if I am reinventing the wheel or not, and I am sure there are improvements that can be made, but I think it should work for you.

**First Note (my choices of design)**: Since you already were willing to try k-means I have stuck with that type of approach. Essentially the down-side of this is that you will need to pick a $K$ (the number of clusters). I would recommend trying a few values and seeing which one gives you the results you would like.

**Second Note (local optima and optimiztion)**: The code I created uses a type of "genetic algorithm" (at least I think thats the correct name for it) to get over local-optima. Essentially it runs `n.unit` optimizations from random initial starting points at the same time, each iteration it takes the worst optimization and replaces it with the best one. Essentially this reduces wasted time working with crappy solutions that are stuck in local optima. Also I use random sampling of group membership to further help get over local-optima. I find it worked quite well on my simulated data and was quite fast.

## First - I simulated data that looks somewhat like yours.

```
library(tidyverse)

lambda <- seq(0.01, .1, by=0.01)
x <- 5:100
pars <- expand.grid("lambda" = lambda, "x" = x)
dat <- cbind(pars$x, exp(-pars$lambda*pars$x))
plot(dat)
```

[image]

## Second - Log-transform your data

I would first suggest you log-transform your values for `Perc_Retired`. This shoud probably make them look much more linear.

```
dat.log <- cbind(dat[,1], log(dat[,2]))
plot(dat.log)
```

[image]

## Third – The Actually "Linear-Regression-K-Means–Thing" I cooked up

```
# Create Design Matrix and Response
X <- cbind(1, dat.log[,1]) # Design matrix, add intercept
Y <- dat.log[,2] # Responses
K <- 10  # Number of Clusters
n.unit <- 10 # Number of parallel optimizations to run
n <- nrow(X) # Number of observations

# Function to convert vector/matrix to probabilities (e.g., normalize to 1)
miniclo <- function (c){
  if (is.vector(c)) 
    c <- matrix(c, nrow = 1)
  (c/rowSums(c)) 
}

# Random Initialize the group assignments. 
gs <- as.list(1:n.unit) %>% 
  map(~sample(1:K, size = nrow(dat.log), replace = TRUE)) 

n.iter <- 100 # Number of iterations to run the optimization for
for (i in 1:n.iter) {
  # Start out by fitting linear regressons to each group
  fits <- gs %>% 
    map(~split(1:n, .x)) %>% 
    at_depth(2, ~lm.fit(X[.x,], Y[.x])) # Fit models

  # Calculate the squared residuals of each data-point to each
  # groups fitted linear model. Note I also add a small value (0.0001)
  # to avoid zero values that can show up later when converting to probabilities
  # and inverting. 
  sq.resids <- fits %>% 
    at_depth(2, "coefficients") %>% # Extract Coefficients
    at_depth(2, ~((Y-X%*%.x)^2)+0.0001) %>%  # Predict and Compute Squared Residuals
    map(bind_cols)

  # Store which "unit" which of the n.unit optimiztions did the 
  # best and which did the worst
  best.worst <- sq.resids %>% 
    map(sum) %>% 
    unlist()
  best.worst <- c(which.min(best.worst), which.max(best.worst))

  # Compute new group assignements, notice I convert the relative
  # squared residual of each model into a probability and then use the 
  # inverse of this probability as the probability that a data-point
  # belongs to that group
  new.gs <- sq.resids  %>% 
    map(miniclo)  %>% # Add small value to fix zeros
    map(~.x^(-1)) %>% 
    map(miniclo) %>% 
    map(~apply(.x, 1, function(x) sample(1:K, 1, replace = TRUE, prob = x))) # Add sampling to get over some minima

  # Replace the worst unit with the best
  new.gs[[best.worst[2]]] <- new.gs[[best.worst[1]]]

  # Update the cluster assignemnts for each unit
  gs <- new.gs
}

# Now investigate results of best unit and plot 
pal <- rainbow(10) 
best.g <- new.gs[[best.worst[1]]]

# Function to enable easier plotting of the results.
plot_groupings <- function(d, g, col=rainbow(length(unique(g)))){
  K <- length(unique(g))
  plot(d)
  for (i in 1:K){
    d.local <- d[g == i,]
    d.local <- d.local[order(d.local[,1]), ]
    lines(d.local, col = col[i], lwd=2)
  }
}
```

First plot on the log-transformed scale that we fit the model on

```
plot_groupings(dat.log, best.g)
```

[image]

Now plot on the original scale of the data

```
plot_groupings(dat, best.g)
```

[image]

As you can see, the model does quite well. A small number of points are miss-classified (this could improve if you increase either `n.unit` or `n.iter` I bet) but in general I am quite pleased with the results.

## Potential Generalizations or Alternatives

Note that this approach, of using squared-residuals as a means of doing k-means clustering is quite general and would work for other models (not just linear models). I would be interested to know if this has been done before (I would be shocked if I am really inventing something new here).

I didn't do too much of a web-search to find this. You could also probably find some good stuff by searching "functional data clustering" or something like that.

Anyways, hope this helps.

## UPDATE: Applied to the data you provided

I applied my model to the data you provided, the only difference is that I also log-transformed No_Races variable (not just the Perc_Retired) variable to linearize the data.

I think the results are a fair bit better than dbscan.

[image]

Comment: If anyone is interested. I actually wrote a blog post based on my answer: http://www.statsathome.com/2017/08/13/a-new-functional-clustering-algorithm/. In addition to more examples it also has more robust code.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment, so I post it as an answer.

My impression is that for this kind of problems, `dbscan` performs well. See, for instance, [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) for a nice visualization of various clustering algorithms and their performance. DBSCAN is implemented in R in a package of the same name. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbscan/vignettes/dbscan.pdf) for the vignette. Needless to say, you need to tune some parameters, but after about a minute of tinkering, I produced the following:

```
library(dbscan)

db <- dbscan(Retirees, eps = 2, minPts = 3)
plot(Retirees, col = db$cluster + 1L, pch = db$cluster + 1L)
```

[image]

This is clearly not perfect, but hey, I spent about a minute on this. I am sure you can improve this with appropriate tuning of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it didn't work is because you forgot to *scale* the data appropriately.

However, I have bad news for you:

### These aren't clusters, but artifacts.

Clearly, some data was discretized at some point prior to transformation, so you get these ugly artifacts. They are not real.

Note that the lines follow 1/x, 2/x etc.

Precisely, **undo the percentages**. Then you'll see you have "clusters" where 1, 2, 3, have retired. Useless "clusters" when it comes to finding anything new.

Comment: Thanks, that's handy to know why they appear. Not as much of a fan of the unnecessary and typically Stack Overflow passive aggressiveness at the end though.